# Polymode markdown: export to revealjs

Tags: markdown, polymode, quarto

I want to export a markdown document to revealjs slides. When I open the markdown file, poymode markdown major mode is activated. When I choose "export" from the menu, I can specify "pandoc's markdown" as input file format, but I don't get any "revealjs" option for the output format. Is it possible to add this option? The corresponding command should be something like `pandoc myfile.md -s -t revealjs -o myfile.html`.

I have tried as a workaround to save the file as quarto markdown. Quarto mode has the option to export to revealjs, but I get an error: "The specified directory ('.') is not a Quarto project". It looks like the problem is in the command issued, that is `quarto render --to=revealjs --output=myfile.html`, it looks like the input file is missing. Is there a way to customize the command to add the input file (I guess it is just matter of adding a `%s`, but I do not know where and how to do it!).

Comment: Customize `markdown-command`